# How do you add manifest files to UWP projects that Unity3D builds?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-runtime

I am porting a game to Windows 10 and Xbox One, which requires that I have certain manifest files in my UWP app for defining the capabilities and socket usage of the application.

I understand the uses of these manifest files; however, I do not understand how I am able to configure the manifests that are built or injected into UWP applications that Unity3D creates when building.

Specifically, I need to add the file `networkmanifest.xml` to my UWP app to define socket usage for use with Xbox Live. [Here is a link to Microsoft's documentation on the manifest file.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/features/multiplayer/xim/concepts/live-xim-manifest#universal-windows-application-uwp-network-manifest-templates)

Research into this area has left me drawing a blank, and I'm not sure if it is because I'm fundamentally looking at this problem wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two good options here:

1. Write a script that automatically gets run after the build (using [OnPostprocessBuild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPostprocessBuildWithReport.OnPostprocessBuild.html)) and copy/inject your manifest into the generated project there.
2. Modify the generated Visual Studio solution and commit the files you modified to your project source control. When building your game from Unity, always build on top of the same modified project. Unity will not overwrite the changes you made.

Comment: So I am able to target the same folder for a UWP build each time I do a build, and have a completely separate repository specifically for that platform? Wow, this is extremely useful information.

Comment: Yeah. Although I personally think that it's easier if you just commit your files to your main repository :).